# Large scaled finite-horizon discrete-time LQR

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, optimal-control, linear-control

### Background

The standard finite-horizon discrete-time LQR is to minimize the quadratic cost below:
\begin{align}
\min_{\mathbf{u}_{1}, \mathbf{u}_{2}, \ldots, \mathbf{u}_{T - 1}} J & = \mathbf{x}_{T}^{\top} \mathbf{Q}_{T} \mathbf{x}_{T} + \sum_{t=0}^{T - 1} \mathbf{x}_{t}^{\top} \mathbf{Q}_{t} \mathbf{x}_{t} + \mathbf{u}_{t}^{\top} \mathbf{R}_{t} \mathbf{u}_{t}\\
& \text{s.t.: } \mathbf{x}_{t + 1} = \mathbf{A}_{t} \mathbf{x}_{t} + \mathbf{B}_{t} \mathbf{u}_{t},
\end{align}
where: $\mathbf{x}_{t} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}, \mathbf{u}_{t} \in \mathbb{R}^{m}, \mathbf{A}_{t}, \mathbf{Q}_{t} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}, \mathbf{B}_{t} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}, \mathbf{R}_{t} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$. Also, the matrices $\mathbf{Q}_{t}$ and $\mathbf{R}_{t}$ are positive-definite.

The optimal controller is linear and given as:
$$\mathbf{u}_{t} = -\mathbf{F}_{t} \mathbf{x}_{t},$$
where:
$$\mathbf{F}_{t} = (\mathbf{R}_{t} + \mathbf{B}^{\top}_{t} \mathbf{P}_{t + 1} \mathbf{B}_{t})^{-1} \mathbf{B}^{\top}_{t} \mathbf{P}_{t + 1} \mathbf{A}_{t},$$
and $\mathbf{P}_{t}$ is found iteratively backwards in time by the dynamic Riccati equation:
\begin{align}
\mathbf{P}_{t} & = \mathbf{A}_{t}^{\top} \mathbf{P}_{t + 1} \mathbf{A}_{t} - \mathbf{A}^{\top}_{t} \mathbf{P}_{t + 1} \mathbf{B}_{t} (\mathbf{R}_{t} + \mathbf{B}^{\top}_{t} \mathbf{P}_{t + 1} \mathbf{B}_{t})^{-1} \mathbf{B}^{\top}_{t} \mathbf{P}_{t + 1} \mathbf{A}_{t} + \mathbf{Q}_{t}\\
& = \mathbf{A}_{t}^{\top} \mathbf{P}_{t + 1} (\mathbf{A}_{t} - \mathbf{B}_{t} \mathbf{F}_{t}) + \mathbf{Q}_{t}.
\end{align}

### Problem

Given the solution, one can calculate the auxiliary variable $\mathbf{P}_{t}$, and then obtain the optimal controller gain $\mathbf{F}_{t - 1}$ backward in time. However, the problem I am working with has a state with very high dimensions, $n > 10^{6}$, while the dimension $m$ of the action is much smaller ($m = 10$). In addition, $\mathbf{A}_{t}, \mathbf{Q}_{t}$ and $\mathbf{R}_{t}$ are diagonal matrices. Strictly following the provided solution consistently results in "out of memory" issue due to the storage of the auxiliary matrix $P_{t}$ which requires $\mathcal{O}(n^{2})$.

I searched for some large-scaled LQR problems, but most of them are about the infinite-horizon, where they approximately solved the algebraic Riccati equation, not the difference Riccati equation.

I wonder if there is a way to handle this large-scaled problem, since at the end, what we need is the controller gain $\mathbf{F} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, which is reasonable to store in the memory.

---

#### Update on Oct 13, 2021

After searching, I found a way to directly solve for action $\mathbf{u}_{t}$ without the auxiliary variable $\mathbf{P}_{t}$. It is to re-parameterize the action as a linear function of the initial state (see [MIT 6.832](http://underactuated.csail.mit.edu/lqr.html#section3) and [Caltech CS159](https://1five9.github.io/slides/control/Lecture_2_OCPs.pdf)). This results in a quadratic optimization for the cost $J$.

---

Comment: What is the structure of $B$, does each input only affect certain states? If so you might be able to decouple each input and its associated states and solve each sub-LQR problem separately, provided that the $Q_t$ and $R_t$ matrices also allow for this. Additionally, have you tried model reduction?

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen $\mathbf{B}_{t}$ is a dense $n \times n$ matrix, hence, the input will affect all of the states. I forgot to mention that $\mathbf{Q}_{t}$ and $\mathbf{R}_{t}$ are also diagonal matrices (will update the question). I have not tried model reduction yet.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen I am new to this field. Could you suggest some reading materials explaining about model reduction?